# Jenkins merge into git master only if each subcomponent build successfully

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to use Jenkins to keep my master branch stable, as described [here](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/03/dont-phunk-with-my-stable-branch.html).  Basically, developers check push into the integration branch and only the Jenkins instance merges from integration into master.  My project consists of multiple RTL (verilog, vhdl, etc) sub-components which each have their own testbench and can be built separately.  The git-plugin supports filtering based on changed files before running a test, but I want to require all the changed subcomponents to build successfully before merging. i.e. If my directory structure looks like:

```
src/
    A/
    B/
    C/
    share/
test/
    A/
    B/
    C/
```

If something in just src/A/ changes, then only test A needs to succeed before merging integration into master.  If src/share/ changes, then tests A, B, and C need to run before merging integration into branch.  All of the tests can be run in parallel.

I've looked into using fork-plugin and parameterized-trigger-plugin, but it looks like they need to be statically configured.  Is there a way of dealing with this type of dynamic dependency diamond and having Jenkins merge integration into master only if everything succeeds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using [gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) to manage changes. There is a Gerrit plugin for Jenkins that will automatically build and test changes submitted by developers. Once changes are verified by Jenkins, they can be reviewed, approved and subsequently merged.